# remotely connect to the Sql server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlconnection

I want to connect to a server using the IP address of the server in the connection string:

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source = IPaddress;" + "Trusted_Connection=yes;" + "Initial Catalog = Real Estate;" + "user id = sa" + "password = password;");
    conn.Open();
    if(conn.State.Equals("Open"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not Connected");
    }
```

why isn't this code working? It always give exception on:
conn.Open();

Comment: Though we are powerful, stackoverflow has not yet evolved the capability to read your mind. Until we do you are going to have to post the error message you are seeing as part of your question.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @TomRedfern

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source = IPaddress;" + 
"Trusted_Connection=yes;" + 
"Initial Catalog = `Real Estate`;" + 
"user id = sa;" + 
"password = password;");
```

First of all, tables with a space in them need to be put between two single quotes under the (~) key. And secondly you forgot (;) after the user id line. I`m guessing this is your problem since you didn't post the full error you're getting.